# Is my answer better off as a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers

Today, I looked at the comments on an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111710/how-could-one-achieve-a-see-through-text-effect-in-ios) question. The answer was mentioning a link which could help the OP, The comments on that answer were clear - **link-only answers are bad. This should be a comment instead**. As I looked at those comments, a horrible realization dawned over me, I had given *an almost similar answer* to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199030/one-thread-writes-data-while-not-being-read-many-threads-read-while-data-is-not/25199148#25199148) question. While I *did* give some details in the answer, I've to confess, I was merely putting what the link already had- Just in my own words.  In my defence, I never put links as answers, but in this answer, the **link had everything**, it would have made little sense to write what a *ReadWriteLock* did all over again. So, I just pointed out the Class did *exactly what the OP wanted*.

I am a little confused, **whether my answer should have been a comment?**.

Comment: You've just overused links in this meta question. Please quote.

Comment: A realization, sure, but horrible? It's not *that* bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view both answers you linked to are fine. The first-one shouldn't been deleted, although it is not a great answer but you use downvotes for that.

If you look at this answer (without the link):

> What you are looking for is a ReadWriteLock . Where multiple threads can read at the same time. A write is blocked until the reading threads finish. And reads are blocked until the writing thread finishes.

It answers this question (paraphrased):

> Which lock should I use if there is 1 "writer" and N "readers"?

The link is an added bonus.

The answer becomes link-only if it would have read like this:

> You need to look  [here](http://www.awesomewebsitewithdocumentation.net)!

The deleted answer looks like this:

> Take a look at method [drawAtPoint:blendMode:alpha:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/drawAtPoint:blendMode:alpha:) of UIImage.

and even without the link it tries to answer the question. It is a minimal answer, it could use some comments to encourage the OP to provide an example how to use that, maybe give it a downvote but it certainly isn't a link-only answer and shouldn't be flagged and if reviewed the action should be *Looks OK*.

Also read the excellent post from Shog9 [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, op didn't write the answer on the first one. I think they saw comments; I'm guessing the post is gone now. For the second one, is the question on topic? Asker is ignorant to the Java utility and is essentially asking for an outside library/resource.

Comment: Wow, I'm not suggesting your part of some mob, nor am I recommending you to take action on the post. Sorry I burdened you with a simple yes/no question.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood or over reacted, sorry about that. The OP is indeed not the answerer of the first answer linked to. He might have seen that answer pop-up in the queue.